# jQuery Font-Family Fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts

I currently have a custom font that is used throughout my site. However, it seems as though with some users, the font doesnt render correctly.

I am trying to create a jQuery function that goes through each element that contains the font-family, and have it fall back to the next available font.

For example, this is my css:

```
li a {
font-size: 1.182em;
font-family: agbookroundedbqmedRg,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

How would I go about creating a jQuery function that goes through each element on the page if the font family matches "agbookroundedbqmedRg", removing it, and setting the new font-family to "Arial", which is next in the list.

I was thinking of doing something along the lines of using the jQuery all selector, comparing font family with the .css(), and hard-coding the "Arial" font.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Css already falls back to Arial, if the first declared font in the fon't family is not loaded, so I can't really see why would you want to do that with javascript? Also what does "not render correctly mean"? Is it not loading, is it not smooth enough?

Comment: It looks as though you are to provide a fallback instead of solving the real problem. **Why does your font not "render correctly". That would make a better question for SO.**

Comment: Yes; try to find out what the differences are between those users who have problems and those who haven't. Different platforms? Connectivity problems?

Comment: By the way, did you intend for the Javascript routine to be invokable by the user, if the font doesn't work on their system? Otherwise, if all it will do is simply remove the font from every element, I'd suggest taking the font out of the stylesheet manually and be done with it. Or, create two stylesheets, one without the font as an alternate, and let the user choose.